# Agregar propiedad headers a solicitud antes de enviar un formulario en html Js o AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente formulario creado con JavaScript nativo, necesito agregar una propiedad al headers para que dicha petición sea autorizada.

```
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.id='formulario_auxiliar';
    form.action = 'url';
    form.method = 'GET';
    form.target = '_blank';
    form.style.display = 'none';


    var myHeaders = new Headers();

    myHeaders.append('Autorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("userToken"));



    form.headers= myHeaders;
```

Comment: No creo que se pueda añadir cabeceras a un formulario si lo envías de forma regular a través del navegador, puedes añadirlas si lo envías utilizando `ajax`:
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias,He buscado mucho, y solo encontré la forma de hacer con ajax pero esta vez estoy utilizando angular js. más abajo un ejemplo de como utilizo. Ahora el headers se puede agregar mediante un interceptor creado, ya que la petición se realiza vía ajax.

```
           $scope.openReport=function(url,type){

            $http({
                method : 'GET',
                url : 'http://localhost:8080/enterprisesoft/'+url,
                responseType: "blob"
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
                 var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/'+type});
                // FileSaver.saveAs(blob, getFileNameFromHttpResponse(response));

                 var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                 $window.open(fileURL);
            }, function errorCallback(response) { 

                console.log(response);
            });


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la propiedad httpProvider de AngularJs.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$httpProvider.
Te enseño como lo tengo hecho yo.

```
app.factory('sessionInjector', ['$q', '$localStorage', '$rootScope', '$location', '$localStorage','$injector',
                                      function($q, $localStorage, $rootScope, $location, $localStorage,$injector) {  


    var sessionInjector = {
        request: function(config) {

            if ( $rootScope.token ) {
                config.headers['token'] = $rootScope.token;
            }

            //return config;
            return config || $q.when(config);
        },       
        responseError: function(errorResponse) {

            var loadingOverlay = $injector.get("$loadingOverlay")           
            loadingOverlay.hide();

            switch (errorResponse.status) {
            case 400:
            case 404:
                break;
            case 401:
                if ($location.$$path != '/') {
                    $localStorage.lastPath = $location.$$path;
                }

                $localStorage.user = null;
                $rootScope.token = null;
                $location.path('/');
                break;
            case 403:
//              showMessage('Error: '+ errorResponse.status +'Acceso no permitido al servicio. ', 'xx-http-error-message alert alert-danger', 10000);
                break;
            case 409:
                break;
            case 423:
                break;
            case 500:
                showMessage('Error interno del servidor: ' + errorResponse.data, 'xx-http-error-message alert alert-danger', 10000);
                break;
            }

            return $q.reject(errorResponse);
        },
        response: function(response){           
            var token = response.headers('token');

            if( token ){
                $rootScope.token = token;
                $localStorage.user.token = token;
            }

            return response ;
        }    

    };

    return sessionInjector;
}]);
```

Y luego en el app.config tengo.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('sessionInjector');
```

Answer (score 0):

Para añadir headers a una petición debes de hacerla por ajax, mi recomendación és que uses jQuery dado que disminuye drásticamente las lineas de código a escribir.

Primero tienes que añadir un listener del form `onSubmit` y usar la la propiedad `.serialize()` de jQuery [Más info](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Después tienes que crear la petición usando la función `.ajax()` de jQuery.

[Documentación .ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

[Ejemplos de añadir headers con .ajax()](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-send-custom-headers-using-jquery-Ajax-and-consume-the-same-header-in-WCF-using-C)

[Más información sobre el tema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516865/how-to-set-a-header-field-on-post-a-form)

Comment: Gracias,He buscado mucho, y solo encontré la forma de hacer con ajax pero esta vez estoy utilizando angular js. más abajo un ejemplo de como utilizo.

Comment: Perfecto, tanto node.js como angular.js y demás funcionan distinto, para recibir una respuesta adecuada como la que tú mismo te has otorgado deberías de añadir en el título de la pregunta o en una etiqueta que estás usando angular.js